# Mobile chat "you have been suspended" notification is too ambiguous

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, mobile-web, chat-ban

Earlier today, I was suspended from chat due to an inappropriate message (I totally deserved it, but that's not the point). I looked at my phone, and this is all that it told me:

[image: This room is read-only]

...which confused me because chat was still moving as normal. I didn't realize that I had been suspended until I checked on my computer to see what the heck was going on.

To me, "This room is read-only" sounds like some sort of database lockup or something related specifically to the room, not the user. It doesn't give any feedback to indicate that the room will be "read-only" for 30 minutes, and doesn't mention that all other rooms are also "read-only". Even a message saying just "You have been suspended from chat" would be more helpful.

Comment: Incidentally, this is still the case on the new mobile chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has apparently been fixed since then.

[image]